# Why might a process block in fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, ...) on OSX?

Tags: c, macos, sqlite, file-locking, fcntl

A new experimental feature of SQLite uses a blocking posix lock at one point. I have a test case where a process is blocked in this fcntl() call on OSX, but I can't see why. The same test works on Linux, but that could just be lucky timing.

The call is:

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &f);
```

where "f" is:

```
$1 = {
  l_start = 120,
  l_len = 1,
  l_pid = 0,
  l_type = 3,
  l_whence = 0
}
```

According to [lsof] my process is the only one that has the file open:

```
bash-3.2$ sudo lsof test.db-shm
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
testfixtu 21393  dan   10u   REG   14,2    32768 228781731 test.db-shm
```

It is possible that some other process was holding a conflicting lock when fcntl() was first called though.

gdb shows that the file descriptor being passed to fcntl() is "10", so I think it is valid.

So my question is, why might fcntl() be blocking if no other processes have the file open?

Comment: Do you have the `lslk` program to examine what file locks are in place?

Comment: Can't seem to get it to build for OSX. It seems to have a custom backend for each different unix it supports - and OSX/FreeBSD is not amongst them. It would be helpful though. Appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: On modern Linux, `fcntl()` locks do not interact with `flock()` locks.  This is the classic BSD situation, too, but apparently these lock types *do* interact on some modern BSDs.  I'm not sure whether OSX/FreeBSD is one of those, but if so then you may be seeing the process deadlock against itself.

Comment: The fcntl/flock factoid is worth filing away for the future. Thanks! It's still not clear why this is happening, but it now seems like an OS bug. 10.6.8 fails but 10.7.5 and newer versions succeed.